# Multiple regression when uncorrelated independent variables to the dependent variable

Tags: statistics, regression

Considering on multiple regression, e.g. `Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3`,
do you think it is worth fitting multiple regression model to data
when `cor(X1, Y)`, `cor(X2, Y)` and `cor(X3, Y)` are all small values such as `0.2`,
moreover the plots of `(X1, Y)`, `(X2, Y)` and `(X3, Y)` are not seen (linearly, non-linearly) uncorrelated?

In summary,

1. When each independent variable is uncorrelated to the dependent variable (visually linearly and non-linearly) is there any possibility that the multiple regression model gives significant coefficients?
2. For the same data, is there any possibility that nonlinear models such as Neural Networks give good predictable result?

Comment: Consider posting your question to https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

**In answer to (1)**, it's *possible* that explanatory variables with low marginal correlations become significant when input into a multiple regression. For example, if X1 and X2 are negatively correlated with one another and both positively influence Y, the relationship between Y and X1 may be confounded by the influence of X2 (and vice versa).

Multiple regressions effectively estimate the relationship between the response and each explanatory variable when controlling for the influence of all other terms in the model, so this confounding is effectively removed. The code at the end of this post shows a hypothetical example.

Having said the above, it seems more likely that your low correlations reflect that your explanatory variables aren't good predictors of your response, rather than being good predictors which are confounding one another. Only one way to find out though.

**In answer to (2)**, it's also *possible* that a non-linear model will give better predictive accuracy than a linear model. In my experience however, if you have low predictive accuracy from one model type, other model types are unlikely to perform well.

Here's that example code I mentioned above:

```
# Make example data
X1 = rnorm(100)
X2 = -X1 + runif(100)/10 #X2 is negatively correlated with X1
Y = X1 + X2 + runif(100)

# Check correlations
cor(X1, Y) #should give low correlation
cor(X2, Y) # should give low correlation
cor(X1, X2) # should give high (negative) correlation

# Fit model and extract pvalues. Should find significant relationships between Y and X1 and X2 despite the low correlations
fit = lm(Y ~ X1 + X2) 
summary(fit)$coefficients[, "Pr(>|t|)"] # pvalues
```

Comment: Happy to help. If my response answered your question would you mind upvoting and accepting it? (In case you're not familiar with how to do this, just click on the up-facing grey triangle to the left of my response (to upvote) and on click on the tick immediately below this (to accept)). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. To use the multi regression model, you should check, that the absolut residuals are normal distributed and the mean of them should be 0. 
   When there is a uncorrelation between dependent and independent variable, than you can transform them:

   - log(x) or square(x). For that there will be a new column in the dataset. This new column should be checked with qq-diagrams for normal distribution. If yes, you use this column. 
     In the end you have to take care in the interpretacion of the data, because they are transformed.
2. To predict a depend variable, nn can help, but you have to try different layers and find the lowest mean square error.